# Seeing the list of articles that cite an article

Tags: arxiv

When looking at an article on arXiv (e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6444) is there anyway to see the list of articles that cited it (putting aside going to some other scholar websites such as Google Scholar)?

Comment: @pnuts Good point, I have just realized that the submenu "Citations to the Article" in the "References & Citations" page only appears when there is at least one citation... Can you please put your comment as an answer? I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: @pnuts The article I pointed to in my answer doesn't have any citation. I had to go to [some 2008 article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.2015) to get one :)